# How to center TextView under ImageView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I wrote the following XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/layout_progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxHeight="50dp"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:minWidth="50dp"
        android:maxWidth="50dp"
        android:theme="@style/progressColor"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/layout_avatar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/layout_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_progressbar"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It's the item of a RecyclerView. It basically tries to create the following layout:

```
[  ImageView  ]
   [TextView]
```

Where the `TextView` is in the center of the `ImageView`. If the TextView is too long it will shorten it and put three dots at the end. But the problem is I can't seem to figure out how to make the `TextView` size to be a bit less then the size of the `ImageView`. Currently it creates:

[image]

The ImageView is set dynamically and it could be of size `50dp-70dp`.

I'm trying to achieve something like:

[image]

How can I do it? I know that I can use `gravity` to be `center` only in `match_parent` but this is a RV item so I want it to be wrap_content.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a `RelativeLayout` you can use [**`android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams#attr_android:layout_centerHorizontal) in the `ProgressBar` and `ImageView`.
If you want to center vertically add also `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`.

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ..>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ..>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how does it limit the `TextView` to have maximum size of the `ImageView`? In your solution `TextView` has bigger width than the `ImageView`.

Comment: @vesii You can fix the `android:layout_width="xxdp"` in your RL or in your `TextView`